# How to deploy streams with 'criteria' in SCDF

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

In [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#_creating_a_simple_stream) guide it is mentioned that during deployment of a stream one can specify for each module a 'criteria' property.
e.g.

```
dataflow:> stream deploy --name ticktock --properties "module.time.count=3,module.log.criteria=groups.contains('x')"
```

The explanation tells only that this property is evaluated against the "attributes of each currently available module".

But what does this mean? Which attributes are considered? What is the purpose of this property at all? What would for example the property mean in the shown example: `module.log.criteria=groups.contains('x')`?

Are these 'criteria' a way to express filter conditions on the incoming messages of the module?

Is there any further documentation to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is unfortunately a mistake in our documentation. This feature used to exist for Spring XD, where the `criteria` were used to target specific containers, and it is not supported by Spring Cloud Data Flow as we do not deploy to containers anymore, but to the target platform: e.g. Cloud Foundry, Mesos, Kubernetes.

We will correct the documentation.